# jQuery Datatables - Bind function to checkbox after ajax source is changed and loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code for initializing my DataTable:

```
var table = $("#table").DataTable();
```

And I have this code to bind a event when the user changes the selected option in a `<select>`

```
$("#select").change(function(){

       var id = $("#select").val();
       if ( !id ){
          return;
       }        

       table.ajax.url( "{% url 'm_data_for_table' 0 %}".replace(0, id) ).load();

});
```

The table reloads with the new rows without problems. This is the content that comes from ajax:

```
 {
    "data": [
        [
            "<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox_select' value='xxx' /> ",
            "John",
            "Python Developer"           
        ],
        [
            "<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox_select' value='xxy' /> ",
            "Renan",
            "JavaScript Developer" 
        ],
        [
            "<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox_select' value='xxz' /> ",
            "Anna",
            "Python Developer" 
        ]
    ]
}
```

I would like to bind a event to the checkboxes after the table is rendered.

How could I do that?

Comment: Use `initComplete` callback to do so. Please include runnable code.

Comment: Will initcomplete runs always after the ajax reloads?

Comment: No. in ajax success handle you should add new rows then redraw the datatable.

Comment: You should try to pass a callback into the load() method : https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url().load()

Comment: Worked like a charm Bernar Pagoaga. Please, post as an answer so I can check as answer.